# Mono.Defer in kotlin not able to delete the data from couchbase using ReactiveCouchbaseRepository

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, couchbase, reactive

Want to delete a data from couchbase by using ReactiveCouchbaseRepository function and its return type is Mono.Defer but when running,its not able to delete from the DB.

Say
ScopeRepository is an interface

```
public interface ScopeRepository : ReactiveCouchbaseRepository<Scope, String>
```

Deleting from DB:

```
 @Autowired
override lateinit var scopeRepository: ScopeRepository

monoDefer.subscribe(scopeRepository.deleteById("scopeId"))
```

even tried this

```
Mono.just(scopeRepository.deleteById("scopeId"))
```

Comment: Is this for Couchbase Lite/Couchbase Mobile?